# How to not allow kinematic physics bodies to pass through static bodies?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

My game scene consist of four walls, which are static bodies, and one platform plate, which is of type kinematic and slides only horizontally, something like the picture below.

[image]

The platform body moves based on acceleration sensor, see this codes

```
@Override
public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
    mPlatformBody.setLinearVelocity(pAccelerationData.getX() * 10, 0);
}
```

My problem is when the platform goes off the boundary walls, which it should not. For resolving this issue, I've set its velocity to zero once it tries to break out the boundaries. see this codes

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(camWidth / 2 - 40, camHeight / 2 - 5,
        80, 10, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

        if (this.getX() <= 1) {
            mPlatformBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }

        if ((this.getX() + 80 >= camWidth - 1)) {
            mPlatformBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
};
```

With the codes above, *still* this platform can goes off the screen.

Could anyone please help me out how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You also have to reset its position to what it was before or just outside the boundaries of the wall, otherwise it will gain some velocity, move a bit, you reset velocity to 0, and so on. It'll be slow but it will still move.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D How can I reset its position?, as far as I know box2d does not provide any method for manually position a body

Comment: You can use the SetTransform function of b2Body to set the position of a body.

Comment: @iforce2d Thanks, `setTransform` sounds like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LearnCocos2D stated, I should reset platform body to a legal position while it tries to leave the screen. For this, I should use `setTransform` method of `Body` class (as @iforce2d said).

For dealing with `setTransform`, there is two important points.

- AndEngine uses *top-left* as anchor of sprites, but Box2d uses *center* as anchor of bodies.
- Box2d uses *meter* as its units, so we must tranform all *pixel* units to meter unit.

**Example:** Suppose we want to move body *body* to (3, 4) point (in pixels).

```
    float x = 3; // in pixels (AndEngine unit)
    float y = 4; // in pixels (AndEngine unit)
    float wD2 = sprite.getWidth()  / 2;
    float hD2 = sprite.getHeight() / 2;
    float angle = body.getAngle(); // preserve original angle

    body.setTransform((x + wD2) / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, 
                      (y + hD2) / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,
                      angle);
```

Note that `PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT` is 32.