# How to move body after Contact is detected

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I don't want to move my static body after a contact from another body is detected, what I did is create a class that implements a `ContactLisner`. I was able to detect when two bodies collides but I had error when I tried to move the bodies.

```
//this is my first try, the idea was to call this method when contact is detected.
public static void movePlatform(){
        platform.setTransform(position.x += 21f, position.y, 0f);
    }

//on my contact listener class

 public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

        Platform.movePlatform();
    }
```

I also tried this but I don't know if it's possible to do this:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

        fb.getBody().setTransform(10f, 0f, 0f);
    }
```

when the body collides to the other body, the desktop application stops responding and i get this message:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information. AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed Assertion
>   failed!
>
> Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe File:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp,
>   Line 419
>
> Expression: m_world->IsLocked() == false

Comment: Also it could be worth looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28380723/1841194).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that the code in the contact listener is called during the simulation step so you can't modify the world there. In other words, the world is locked. One way of solving the problem is to have `Gdx.app.postRunnable`. So in your example try:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run () {
                    fb.getBody().setTransform(10f, 0f, 0f);
                }
        });
}
```

This will run the code in the Runnable in the rendering thread in the next frame.

**Edit:**

In `beginContact` the rendering thread is locked which means that you can't move or manipulate any box2d related bodies). This is required by box2d to work properly. Runnable is a special interface in Java which is implemented by the class Thread. This will open a new thread and will pass data to the rendering thread in the next frame. I would suggest you reading more about [libgdx threading](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading)

Comment: thanks it worked, but can you please explain what beginContact() method does?

Comment: I'm new to programming in general, this is the first time I've encountered this kind of code. A method that has a method inside.